# React and Angular Grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, reactjs

I am developing an react and angular js grid .

Here is my Code :

While Page load it calls the  `gen(dataSetOne);` function and grid loads perfectly . But on the second time when i try to load tables with different set of json values via button click it fails !  Any idea how to rectify it

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html ng-app="example">
    <head>
        <title>ngReactGrid Basic Example</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../build/css/ngReactGrid.css">
    </head>
    <body>
    <div ng-controller="BasicExampleController" style="width: 100%">
        <ng-react-grid grid="grid"></ng-react-grid>
    </div>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"
            src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.4/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://fb.me/react-0.12.1.js"></script>
    <script src="./dataSet.js"></script>
    <script src="../build/js/ngReactGrid.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">


        gen(dataSetOne);
        function gen(dataSet){

            console.log(dataSet);



            angular.module("example", ['ngReactGrid'])
                    .controller("BasicExampleController", function ($scope, $timeout,
                                                                    ngReactGridCheckbox, ngReactGridTextField) {
                        console.log("in");

                        $scope.employee = {};
                        $scope.selections = [];
                        $scope.clickedOnRecord = {};
                        $scope.editingGrid = false;

                        $scope.isEditing = function () {
                            return $scope.editingGrid;
                        };

                        var checkboxGrid =
                                new ngReactGridCheckbox($scope.selections,
                                        {batchToggle: true,
                                            disableCheckboxField: 'disableCheckbox'});

                        var checkboxState = false;
                        $scope.toggleVisibleCheckboxes = function () {
                            checkboxState = !checkboxState;
                            checkboxGrid.setVisibleCheckboxState(checkboxState);
                        };

                        $scope.edit = function () {
                            $scope.grid.edit();
                            $scope.editingGrid = true;
                        };

                        $scope.save = function () {
                            var data = $scope.grid.save();
                            console.debug('data', data);
                            $scope.editingGrid = false;
                        };

                        $scope.cancel = function () {
                            $scope.editingGrid = false;
                            $scope.grid.cancel();
                        };

                        var referenceData = dataSet.slice(0, 100).map(function (rec) {
                            return {
                                id: rec.firstName,
                                name: rec.firstName
                            }
                        });

                        var isOddRow = function(index) {
                            return (index % 2) === 0;
                        };
                        dataSet = dataSet.map(function (rec, index) {
                            return {
                                user: {
                                    firstName: rec.firstName,
                                    lastName: rec.lastName,
                                    state: rec.state,
                                    zip: rec.zip,
                                    country: rec.country
                                },
                                disableCheckbox: isOddRow(index)
                            };
                        });

                        $scope.grid = {
                            data: dataSet,
                            columnDefs: [
                                checkboxGrid,
                                {
                                    field: "user.firstName",
                                    columnFilter: true,
                                    displayName: "First Name",
                                    edit: function (row) {
                                        return new ngReactGridTextField(row, 'user.firstName');
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    field: "user.lastName",
                                    columnFilter: true,
                                    displayName: "Last Name"
                                },
                                {
                                    field: "user.city",
                                    columnFilter: true,
                                    displayName: "city"
                                },
                                {
                                    field: "user.city",
                                    columnFilter: true,
                                    displayName: "city"
                                },
                                {
                                    field: "user.state",
                                    columnFilter: true,
                                    displayName: "state"
                                },
                                {
                                    field: "user.zip",
                                    columnFilter: true,
                                    displayName: "zip"
                                },
                                {
                                    field: "user.country",
                                    columnFilter: true,
                                    displayName: "country"
                                }
                            ]
                        };

                    });
        }

        function make(dataSet){

            console.log("here" + dataSet);
        }

    </script>


    <button id="gen" onclick="gen(dataSetTwo)">Generate</button>
    </body>
    </html>




    var dataSetTwo = [{
        "firstName": "ViVVVjay0",
        "lastName": "Vijay0",
        "city": "New York0",
        "state": "New York0",
        "zip": "192030",
        "country": "United States0",
        "phone": "123-455-67530",
        "email": "test@gmail.com0"
    }, {
        "firstName": "JJJJJJJJJose1",
        "lastName": "Garcia1",
        "city": "New York1",
        "state": "New York1",
        "zip": "192031",
        "country": "United States1",
        "phone": "123-455-67531",
        "email": "test@gmail.com1"
    }];

var dataSetOne = [{
    "firstName": "Vijay0",
    "lastName": "Vijay0",
    "city": "New York0",
    "state": "New York0",
    "zip": "192030",
    "country": "United States0",
    "phone": "123-455-67530",
    "email": "test@gmail.com0"
}, {
    "firstName": "Jose1",
    "lastName": "Garcia1",
    "city": "New York1",
    "state": "New York1",
    "zip": "192031",
    "country": "United States1",
    "phone": "123-455-67531",
    "email": "test@gmail.com1"
}];
```

Here is my fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/jarvis_mutant/2mrLm4z9/

Comment: A plunk or jsfiddle would be helpful, and also any errors/warnings you get ("it fails" isn't very clear).

Comment: Hi ! i have added fiddle ! Can u please see it ??

Comment: You just pasted your code into a fiddle, it doesn't actually do anything.  The point of a fiddle is so someone can make changes and see if it fixed the problem.